# What is the name of the scale E, F#, G, A, B, C, D#?

Tags: scales, modes

I am fairly new to music theory, and I came across this kind of scale from a piano piece.

From what I can tell, this is just e minor with a sharp d. What would this scale be called?

Comment: Are both sharps notated for the whole staff as the key signature, or just accidental?

Comment: The D# is notated as an accidental, but it only appears in the composition as a D#.

Comment: You deduce the scale from the staff key signature, even if accidentals are common throughout the piece. Hence, the scale has only 1 sharp. You deduced correctly tat it is e minor, and others have explained why there is a sharp for the d.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's E *harmonic* minor. the key signature for this is one sharp - F#, as it's the relative minor of G major. The D# is there for a good purpose. Without it, the notes are those of E *natural* minor, and the leading note would be a whole tone away from the tonic. This makes it sound less convincing in tunes, so it's sharpened to make it a semitone away, just like in the major scale/key. Because it doesn't get used *all* of the time in tunes in E minor, it needs to have the # sign attached whenever it does.

Answer (score 3):

As already said by others it is called Harmonic Minor scale, here is a diagram on my website:
 https://www.grunfy.com/scale/582350224/harmonic-minor.html

[image: E Harmonic Minor]

Comment: Note that you must explicitly state it's your own website your linking to: please read [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).

Comment: @Glorfindel  I didn't know about that rule, sorry for that, and yes, above site is my own, but not commercially exploited, hopefully that's not against the rules

Comment: No problem, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

[Scales-Chords](https://www.scales-chords.com/fscale_res_en.php?rn1=E&rn2=F%23%2FGb&rn3=G&rn4=A&rn5=B&rn6=C&rn7=D%23%2FEb&rn8=&rn9=&normal=1&greek=1&greekalt=1&other=1&etnic=1&c1=&t1=&c2=&t2=&c3=&t3=) says either E harmonic minor or E mohammedan.

Comment: E harmonic minor is by far the more common name for that scale. I've never heard of "E mohammedan" before.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - Seems like one person in the world calls it that ! It was posted on 'Ultimate Guitar' - which is hardly a bible - in 2007...

Comment: I hadn't heard of mohammedan scales either, but on looking, it appears to be a thing, on account of the upper tetrachord being a common scale pattern in Middle Eastern music.

Answer (score 0):

This scale starts on E and has a minor third (G), so we can call it some sort of a minor scale. It also has the minor 6th (C), so we know that it isn't E Dorian. The major second, F♯, proves that this is not Phrygian, and with that we've narrowed it down to a derivatve of the minor (Aeolian) mode. Assuming that the D♯s are accidentals and not in the key signature, we can then call this E harmonic Minor.